# Extract same information from duplicated rows based on partial matches

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe, where some of the rows have partial matches:

```py
id   name    affiliation
1    David   Department of Biology, State University
2    Peter   Dept. of Chemistry
1    David   Biology Department, University of State
2    Peter   Chemistry Dept. 
1    David   Department for Zoology, 2nd State University
```

The id 1 and 2 are duplicated based on the id and names however the affiliations make these rows as unique (due to different spellings). I have tried the duplicate function in pandas but that matches complete cell strings and could not find a partial string match function.

Is there a way to get common strings from the affiliations to make the rows unique?

Desired dataframe should look like:

```py
id   name    affiliation
1    David   Biology Department, State University
2    Peter   Dept. Chemistry 
1    David   Department for Zoology, 2nd State University
```

or

```py
id   name    affiliation
1    David   Department Biology, State University
2    Peter   Chemistry Dept. 
1    David   Department for Zoology, 2nd State University
```

Comment: Well this is feasible but subjective. What are your rules to decide whether two affiliations are identical? Should "Dept. of Chemistry" and "Dept. of Chemistry, State University"  match? Then how would you make the difference with "Dept. of Chemistry, Other-State University"?

Comment: what comes to my mind about the rules is to compare complete words in both cells, then split the cells into two columns: one for similar words and one for different words. The different words column can then be filtered one another rule or perhaps based on some stopwords.

Comment: Then why don't you think a bit of those rules, come up with some examples, an initial code and post it in your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using the Python standard library [difflib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html) module, which provides helpers for computing deltas, like this:

**Setup**

```py
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

import pandas as pd

# Original dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "id": [1, 2, 1, 2, 1],
        "name": ["David", "Peter", "David", "Peter", "David"],
        "affiliation": [
            "Department of Biology, State University",
            "Dept. of Chemistry",
            "Biology Department, University of State",
            "Chemistry Dept.",
            "Department for Zoology, 2nd State University",
        ],
    }
)
print(df)
# Outputs
   id   name                                   affiliation
0   1  David       Department of Biology, State University
1   2  Peter                            Dept. of Chemistry
2   1  David       Biology Department, University of State
3   2  Peter                               Chemistry Dept.
4   1  David  Department for Zoology, 2nd State University
```

**Find and delete similar rows**

```py
# Sort "affiliation" column by increasing length
length_increasing = df["affiliation"].str.len().sort_values().index
df = df.reindex(length_increasing)

# Iterate on each value
for affiliation in df["affiliation"].values:
    for row in df.iterrows():
        if row[1]["affiliation"] == affiliation:
            continue
        # Words to compare
        words = sorted(str(affiliation)) 
        other_words = sorted(str(row[1]["affiliation"])[: len(words)])
        # Replace "affiliation" value if significant match ratio
        if SequenceMatcher(None, words, other_words).ratio() > 0.9:
            df.loc[row[0], "affiliation"] = affiliation

# Drop duplicated rows and clean up
df = (
    df.drop_duplicates(subset="affiliation")
    .sort_values(["id", "affiliation"])
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

**Result**

```py
print(df)
# Outputs
   id   name                                   affiliation
0   1  David  Department for Zoology, 2nd State University
1   1  David       Department of Biology, State University
2   2  Peter                            Dept. of Chemistry
```