# How to compare two columns with partial names in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am comparing a list of endangered species names and cross referencing them with a list of species names to figure out if they are on the endangered species list or not but the naming convention on my species list is not identical to the endangered species list. I'd like to compare both columns to see if there is a partial match in the names using Python. This is what I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd

d1 = pd.read_csv('endangered-fish.csv')
d2 = pd.read_csv('fish.csv')
d1.head()
```

[image: 1]

```
d2.head()
```

[image: 2]

```
# rename the existing DataFrame (rather than creating a copy) 
d1.rename(columns={'Common Name': 'common_name'}, inplace=True)
d2.rename(columns={'name': 'ac_name'}, inplace=True)
combined_fish = pd.concat([d1["common_name"],d2["ac_name"]],axis=1)
combined_fish.to_csv("result-fish.csv",index=False)
fish = pd.read_csv('result-fish.csv')
fish.head()
```

[image: 3]

```
d1['common_name'].isin(d2['ac_name']).value_counts()
```

[image: 4]

This only gets me an identical match but since the names are slightly different, I want to compare both columns with any partial match to any row.

Comment: Use fuzzy search: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-do-fuzzy-matching-on-pandas-dataframe-column-using-python/

Comment: Hi, have a look at one of these posts: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68565272/11246056, https://stackoverflow.com/a/68782018/11246056, https://stackoverflow.com/a/69778314/11246056